# Highcharts Standalone Framework is empty

Tags: highcharts

I downloaded Highcharts using bower. The file bower_components/highcharts/adapters/standalone-framework.js is empty. I also looked at the CDN version at http://code.highcharts.com/adapters/standalone-framework.js - it's also empty. Is this intentional?

Comment: In the newest highcharts, standalone-framwork is included in highcharts.js

Comment: That's awesome! I couldn't find a reference to this on the standalone-framework page. Could you please, put this as an answer so that I can mark it correct?

Comment: ...because it's *THAT* lightweight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 4.2 version, the standalone-framework is included in the highcharts.js core.

More information you can find here: http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/198-highcharts-drops-adapters